# java connection, прекращение соединения в связи долгого бездействия

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, client

В своем приложении я создаю connection в "main" и передаю его в контроллеры. Соответственно по истечению долгого простоя соединение закрывается...
Вопрос как этого не допускать не создавая connection каждый раз когда вызывается оперирующий с ним метод, и не создавать отлавливая его в try?
Считаю вышеперечисленные решения не правильными, но если другого нет, то хочу все равно услышать какой из методов вы используете...

Comment: Мы не держим соединения открытыми дольше необходимого минимума, тем более - во время "долгого простоя".

Comment: @igor вопрос в производительности и стандарте, есть период времени в котором к серверу не приходят запросы, которого достаточно для его закрытия. В остальное время он не простаивает без дела. Connection о котором я говорю, это соединение с базой данных MySQL.